# saving comments for different content type

Tags: php, mysql

i have different content types on my website.
f.e. - articles, questions, posts
i see two ways for storing comments.

1) for each content type create table like articles_comments, post_comments etc.

2) create one table with fields parent_field and parent_id. in 'parent_field' save smth like articles_id or posts_id. so with

```
explode('_', $parent_field);
```

I can recieve parent table name and field name for

```
select "... FROM $table WHERE $field = $parent_id"
```

second way seems mor flexible, but first easier.

so, the question is: which way is better, in case of 100+k hosts everyday?

Comment: In terms of performance, smaller tables are probably going to be faster, but since you are going to access only by primary key there is going to be little difference (and case 2 is easier to mantain). Just be sure to use <parent_field, parent_id> together as primary key in case 2.

Answer (score 1):

one table solely for comments

```
id, caption, body, ...
```

one relation table to store the parent relationship to the comment

```
comment_id (int), 
parent_id (int),
parent_type (enum, set, or int BUT not varchar)
// build index
```

which this, you can easily tagged comment to multiple parents (if you want to),
and also can easily do `INNER JOIN` to get comments belong to a parent

another benefit,
such as if you want to get most comments for all article,question and post,
in your method,
you would require three INNER JOIN + GROUP BY,
with my suggestion, you only need single query

most importantly,
the relation table is able to handle huge amount of records
because it only store integer (smaller index)

Comment: and what about performance? for you have to take data from two tables. in case2 i can prepare query in php and use only one table

Comment: it will be better than one single bloated table. One simple example, if you don't have the type -> you will change to use OR (posts_id=? OR articles_id=?) ... then it will not going to make use of any index because index don't do OR across multiple columns. my suggestion allow use of index even with the absent of parent_type